# Error Overloading << in C++

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to overload the << operator. I have defined in my header file as follows:

```
&operator<<(std::ostream &o, const gVector3 &v)
```

And I've defined it in my cpp file like this:

```
std::ostream &gVector3::operator<<(std::ostream &o, const gVector3 &v){
   return o << "The vector elements are" << v[0] << v[1] << v[2];
}
```

I get the following error message. Does anyone know why?

```
C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\Homework1\gVector3.cpp:112: error: 'std::ostream& gVector3::operator<<(std::ostream&,
const gVector3&)' must take exactly one argument
std::ostream &gVector3::operator<<(std::ostream &o, const gVector3 &v){
```

Your help is very much appreciated!
                                                                      ^

Comment: Please get a basic C++ textbook, or read *any* tutorial on the subject you can find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put the declaration inside a class definition, which for the compiler means that it's a member function - operators as class members can only take one argument. The other argument is the object you'll be calling it on. Example for easier understanding:

```
struct Foo {
    void operator<<(int) { }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f << 5;
    // can be also called like this:
    f.operator<<(5);
}
```

What you need is a `friend` specifier to tell the compiler that you're declaring a non-member:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &o, const gVector3 &v)
```

Another example this time with non-member:

```
struct Foo {
    friend void operator<<(Foo, int) { }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f << 5;
    // this time, it can be called like this:
    operator<<(f, 5);
}
```

This is assuming the operator needs access to `gVector3`s private data. If not, drop `friend` and declare it outside the class.

Comment: Ok I see my mistake now. I defined it outside the class. Thanks!